# JWT for BSON (Binary JSON)

Tags: jwt, bson

I would like to sign BSON objects so they can be cryptographically authenticated.  JWT does what I want for JSON, but it seems a bit wasteful to convert the binary object into base64 so it can be signed with JWT.

Is there an equivalent Web Token for BSON?   I'd like to stay with existing solutions (especially one widely adapted) before I roll my own.